# difficulty building civix.phar

Tags: extension

I am using xampp on ubuntu 15.04, with CiviCRM 4.7 and Dupal 7 installed.
I am following the tutorial here:

- https://github.com/totten/civix/blob/master/README.md

I have git and composer installed. I have also installed box as indicated here:

- http://box-project.github.io/box2/

When I run the command:

```
php -dphar.readonly=0 `which box` build
```

I get the error:

> Could not open input file: build

I have installed civix and need to create an extension. Is it ok if I just skip the build process?

Comment: I spoke with the 1 I suppose owns the github account where this documentation is put and he modified the installation process. He seemingly took off the line where the build had to be done